# How to compare two dates from different dimensions in the Cube MDX

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, mdx, olap-cube

I need to create a calculation or KPI (I am not sure what exactly) which helps to compare to dates from different dimensions.

I have a cube and I need run a report when I pick up Course date and Absence date for a student if the dates are the same then a value should be missing.

This is a SQL query which is perfectly working but I need to implement it in a cube:

```
case when AbsenceDate=CourseDate then'missing'
else 'not the same date' End as 'date info'
```

Comment: in `mdx` you have the `Case` construct and also `iif`

Answer (score 0):

If I was writing a script and needed the measure, it would probably look vaguely like this:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[date info] AS
    IIF(
       [AbsenceDate].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
         = [CourseDate].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
       ,NULL
       ,'not the same date'
    )
SELECT
  ...
  ...
```